# How do I store extremely long integers in python sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite, integer

```py
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE "test_table" (number INTEGER)')
c.execute('INSERT INTO test_table (number) VALUES (?)', (9223372036854775807,))  # the max integer size sqlite3 supports'

# this works
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table")
print(c.fetchall())

# this does not. OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER
c.execute('INSERT INTO test_table (number) VALUES (?)', (int(f'1{"0" * 100}'),))
```

I've ran into a limitation with sqlite3. I need to be able to store insanely long numbers. Longer than sqlite3's limit of 9223372036854775807. A bandaid solution I thought of was instead of storing an integer, I store a string, which is the stringed form of the python integer passed and then `int()` it back when querying. However I am unable to SELECT with ORDER BY. Otherwise, it orders in alphabetical order, not by the expected numerical order. Is there a solution to store larger integers or SELECT with ORDER BY without querying the entire database manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you zero-pad your integers to all have the same width (e.g. 100 digits if you know that's your maximum), then alphabetical order will match the numerical order.

Comment: Thanks. It's not flawless since there still is some sort of max, and other problems for my specific application but it works...even if its still very jank.